# Will the absence of connected charger increase the cycle count?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, charging

I'm a new MacBook user, so I may be relying on rumours instead of fact.

It sounds quite silly, but, from my perspective, if I always hold my laptop connected to a charger, then my battery is always around 100% and it seems like the battery cycle count is not growing at that time. And, if I take my laptop somewhere without a charger, then I get this 40-60% decrease, then I think it's at this moment the cycle count increases more than it would if it is connected to a charger.

I guess I'm a little confused by cycle counts. What are the facts about how they are measured?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Unfortunately, your question doesn't provide enough clarity for us to help you. Reading [how to ask a question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) may improve your chances of getting a good answer. Can you please edit your question to clarify what you meany by _at that time the cycle counter increases more than in the first case_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure I understand your question, but one cycle is *equivalent* to a **full** discharge then recharge.

So, using your example, if you use the MacBook without a charger and its charge decreases by 40% and then you recharge it, that's effectively .4 of a cycle.

In other words, to use a simpler scenario, if you use half of your MacBook's charge in one day, and then recharge it fully, and then the next day you do exactly the same, those two days combined would count as one charge cycle.

So, some users may go through a cycle a day, others can use their MacBook for weeks before completing a cycle.

For more info on this refer to [Determining battery cycle count for Mac notebooks](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201585).

Comment: thanks! if we imagine the situation when I'm always using charger and never disconnect it, I could even "stop" the cycle count at all ? :)

Comment: Well, no, not exactly. A new MacBook battery will be rated by Apple as having a certain number of cycles. For example, all 2016 MacBook Pro models have batteries rated by Apple as having 1,000 battery cycles. If you always kept your MacBook plugged into AC power, this doesn't mean you're _stopping_ the cycle count, it just means that the cycle count is happening a __lot__ slower! :)

Comment: As an aside, there are other factors that affect battery life, so if you were to buy a new MacBook Pro today and always keep it plugged into AC power, that doesn't mean your battery will last forever.